# How do I include SQL CE using WiX installer?

Tags: wix, sql-server-ce, wix3.5

So I'm trying to build an installer in Wix 3.5.

My app need SQL CE 3.5 to run.  It looks like MS's installer has an easy way to include this, but I'm not sure what I need to do in WiX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL CE supports an MSI or Private deployment model.  If you opt for the MSI model so Windows Update can service it, you'll need a bootstrapper / chainer which is something WiX doesn't have yet.  If you go for the deployment model you can just deploy the 7 sql ce files privately so your application can find them.  Note if there's any future security fixes and what not you'll have to service them by deploying a new patch or installer for your application.

[How to: Deploy a SQL Server Compact Edition Database with an Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: So there is no MSM module for SQL CE then.  That's dissapointing.

Comment: I generally wouldn't use a merge module even if there was one.  That introduces additional servicing problems.

Comment: I have tried the private deployment of SQL CE and it doesn't seem to work when you're using Linq to SQL.

Comment: Actually found that article in my hours of searching. Tried it, and it _almost_ works. The program wasn't able to create a new SQL CE database, and I wasn't able to test if it could connect to an already existing one.

Comment: Could you just install an empty SDF file and then File.Copy() it?

Comment: I got it to work. Turns out I didn't have the exact dll version string in the .config file correct. Also, I ran into a problem when multiple dlls in my app want to use Linq to SQL - haven't gotten to the bottom of that either. Regardless, installing SQL CE separately looks like the easiest and most reliable option.

Comment: I agree. I prefer to install it as it's own MSI using a bootstrapper so Microsoft can service it via Windows Update.  When you deploy it privatly you have to service it yourself with patches and updates to your product.  Sometimes this is a good thing but usually it isn't.